# Find the next numbers in series?

Tags: logical-deduction

Can you determine the next numbers in the below sequence?
Here is the series. You need to find the possible numbers in 7th line. Series starts with 1 and it is like this.
1
1 1
2 1
1 1 1 2
3 1 1 2
2 1 1 2 1 3
...........

Please try yourself before searching in internet. 
**Note**: I'll post some hints if nobody gets the answer.

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate puzzle, though. The see-and-say follows a different pattern here.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a duplicate question, if you read better you find out that the sequences are different.

Comment: i like this variant form of one of my favorite riddles / number sequences +1

Comment: I think the two are minor variants of each other, enough to be considered duplicates. If you know the answer to one, you know the answer to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 1 2 2 1 3
In fact, in the last line there are 3 "one", 2 "two" and 1 "three"

Everytime, you count the number of the "one" in the previous line, then write that number followed by 1.
Then, you count the "two" and write that number followed by 2.
You keep doing that until the numbers are over.
Also, if a number is missing from the string (for example 2 is missing in 4 1 1 3 1 4), you just ignore it.

Comment: Very clear solution.